# Power Pivot - Join on two tables in separate databases

Tags: sql, powerpivot, dax

I have searched and cannot find an answer to this, so apologies if someone else has already posted a similar question and answer.

Is it possible within powerpivot to join two seperate databases on a table.

I don't have access to the powerpivot, and I am trying to help a friend, who is in the lurch.

In SQL I would do something like the below

```
SELECT 
       FirstDataBaseTable.userID 
FROM   databaseA.dbo.Table FirstDataBaseTable 
INNERJOIN
       databaseB.dbo.Table SecondDatabaseTable  
ON        
       FirstDataBaseTable.userID=SecondDataBaseTable.userID
```

Is the same thing possible?

Best Regards,

SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerpivot is not really made to make this kind of inner join. 
You would rather add a 3th table users, and relate both tables to this 3th table.

If you really want to join tables, it's better to use powerquery.